# what is meaning of '&' combined with when expression in magento2 less file?

Tags: magento2

```
& when (@media-common = true) {
```

what is the meaning of '&' here?
it was Parent Selectors?

Answer (score 1):

`& when` = `if` statement

`&` = referencing parent selectors

see [lesscss DOC](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-guard-logical-operators), [selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-default-variables)

Comment: thanks for your answer, if like that, what is parent selectors? I did not find any parent selector code. That file was imported directly. regards